# Scraping shared outlook calendar by name from another user in pywin32?

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

So I know how to read a user's own personal shared calendar through pywin32 and getSharedDefaultFolder, but I am trying to scrape a shared calendar that is not their personal calendar that is under a different name. Is there a way using pywin32 to get a calendar from a user by calendar name? or specify which calendar to grab out of that user's calendars? I cannot find it in the documentation if it exists

edit:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')  

  
recipient = outlook.CreateRecipient("User Name")      
resolved = recipient.Resolve()    

calendar = outlook.getSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, 9).Folders.Item("Calendar Name").Items
```

Comment: Where is that calendar shown in Outlook? How was it added?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko the calendar is under the "shared calendars" tab in the calendar section of Outlook. It was created by another user, and shared with multiple other users for all of them to input meetings, including myself.

Comment: "Shared Calendars" entries come from other users' mailboxes which can be accessed using `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder`

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Do you know which enumeration it corresponds to to access other users' mailboxes? I am currently using getSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, 9) to return that person's personal calendar, but all other enumerations I can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders) don't allow me to find the shared calendars/other mailbox. I have tried getSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, 9).Folders("calendar name").Items but I am getting some errors

Comment: If the mailboxes was added to the profile, you can try to find it in the N`amespace.Stores` collection. From there, you can open any child folder using `Store.GertRootFolder()`

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I cannot get `store.getrootfolder` to return anything but an attribute error, I have updated the post with the code I am trying above, I seem to be getting a calendar object but it is empty (I am passing in my own username, as when I pass in the username of the person who made the calendar, that also gives an error) I know the name of the calendar in outlook but I just can't seem to access it? Since the calendar was made by the other user, I know I should use their username as the recipient instead of mine but I keep running into blocks

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko The above code block returns a <COMObject <unknown>>, but it is empty and doesnt have any of the calendar appointments in it

Comment: Which code? GetRootFolder()?

Comment: I am also having this issue where I can't access a shared folder with pywin32. I had come across this before, and I just asked the calendar owner if I could recreate the calendar and give everyone else the permissions they needed. I don't think that will work this time, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared `Calendar` folder).

Here is the sample VBA code (I am not familiar with Python, sorry):

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene A.")
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
 
End Sub
```

Also you can get the required Calendar folder using the [NavigationGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.navigationgroup) class which represents a navigation group displayed by a navigation module in the navigation pane.

The following sample in VBA (the Outlook object model is common for all kind of programming languages) counts the number of navigation folders selected for display in the `Calendar` navigation module of the `Navigation Pane`.

```
Dim WithEvents objPane As NavigationPane 
 
Private Sub EnumerateActiveCalendarFolders() 
 Dim objModule As CalendarModule 
 Dim objGroup As NavigationGroup 
 Dim objFolder As NavigationFolder 
 Dim intCounter As Integer 
 
 On Error GoTo ErrRoutine 
 
 ' Get the NavigationPane object for the 
 ' currently displayed Explorer object. 
 Set objPane = Application.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane 
 
 ' Get the CalendarModule object, if one exists, 
 ' for the current Navigation Pane. 
 Set objModule = objPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar) 
 
 ' Iterate through each NavigationGroup contained 
 ' by the CalendarModule. 
 For Each objGroup In objModule.NavigationGroups 
 ' Iterate through each NavigationFolder contained 
 ' by the NavigationGroup. 
 For Each objFolder In objGroup.NavigationFolders 
 ' Check if the folder is selected. 
 If objFolder.IsSelected Then 
 intCounter = intCounter + 1 
 End If 
 Next 
 Next 
 
 ' Display the results. 
 MsgBox "There are " & intCounter & " selected calendars in the Calendar module." 
 
EndRoutine: 
 On Error GoTo 0 
 Set objFolder = Nothing 
 Set objGroup = Nothing 
 Set objModule = Nothing 
 Set objPane = Nothing 
 intCounter = 0 
 Exit Sub 
 
ErrRoutine: 
 MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, _ 
 vbOKOnly Or vbCritical, _ 
 "EnumerateActiveCalendarFolders" 
End Sub
```

So, if you know the calendar name you can easily find the corresponding folder instance using the navigation groups in Outlook.